# Custom keyboard shortcuts keypresses

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcuts, remapping, xdotool

I'm looking for a solution to map keyboard shortcuts to keypresses in a gnome DE. In the scope of this question, I'll use the example of mapping `meta+2` to `F2`. It doesn't seem to work with Xdotool. E.g., when creating a shortcut that triggers `xdotool key F2` and trying to trigger the rename dialog in Nautilus has no result. I also tried mapping it to other keys than the meta key (in this example like ctrl+2) just to be sure it's not how the meta key is handled.

Using the Plasma DE for a long time it was pretty straightforward via the GUI settings. Just went to settings > custom keyboard shortcuts and assigned a keyboard input to a shortcut.

Edit:

```bash
~/git/qmk_firmware master* ❯ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11
```

Edit 2: What I think could be the case, is that `xdotool` adds the keypress to the held modifier. So the F2 key that's sent by `xdotool` becomes meta+F2. This assumption comes from mapping `Alt+2` to `F2` behaves as `Alt+F2`. Is there a way to suppress the held keys, so that the system just recognizes the `xdotool` key?

Comment: Edit your question and include information about your Ubuntu version. If you are using 22.04, you are quite definitely on Wayland. xdotool does not work on Wayland.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the indication but even when I would use the ubuntu distro, in any version I would swap to x11, just because wayland currently still has some essentials lacking that i need for daily work unfortunately. I'm using xdotool for other things and it's definetly working

Answer (score 0):

Found a "usable" workaround.

This is: adding a slight delay to the command `xdotool sleep 0.2 key F2` and not holding down meta-/ctrl-/alt-/(whatever-) key when pressing `2` but just pressing them quickly one after the other has the desired result.

---

Still looking for better solutions though, as this workaround works in the given example (nautlius) but unforunately doesn't in environments like e.g. neovim

Comment: Use "keyup" to have xdotool release your shortcut key before issuing an F2

Comment: Very nice, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use `--clearmodifiers` like `xdotool type --clearmodifiers "admin"`